# Kusto: How can I get the value from the column that doesn't participate in a SUMMARIZE?

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer

Having the below table and Kusto query, how can I obtain a result that has the Purchase column?

```
let ProductsTable = datatable(Supplier: string, Fruit: string, Price: int, Purchase: datetime)
[
    'Contoso', 'Grapes', 220, datetime(2018-10-01 01:00),
    'Fabrikam', 'Lemons', 31, datetime(2018-10-01 02:00),
    'Contoso', 'Lemons', 29, datetime(2018-10-02 03:00),
    'Contoso', 'Grapes', 210, datetime(2018-10-02 04:00),
    'Fabrikam', 'Lemons', 30, datetime(2018-10-03 05:00),
    'Contoso', 'Bananas', 12, datetime(2018-10-03 06:00),
    'Contoso', 'Bananas', 12, datetime(2018-10-04 07:00),
    'Contoso', 'Lemons', 29, datetime(2018-10-04 08:00),
    'Contoso', 'Grapes', 200, datetime(2018-10-05 09:00),
];
ProductsTable
    | summarize Price = min(Price) by Supplier, Fruit
    | order by Supplier asc, Fruit asc, Price asc
```

Result

```
Contoso Bananas 12
Contoso Grapes      200
Contoso Lemons      29
Fabrikam    Lemons      30
```

DESIRED Result

```
Contoso Bananas 12  2018-10-03 06:00
Contoso Grapes      200 2018-10-05 09:00
Contoso Lemons      29  2018-10-02 03:00
Fabrikam    Lemons      30  2018-10-03 05:00
```

I know that there could be multiple results, for example for ***Contoso-Bananas-12*** we can have any of the following

- 2018-10-03 0**6**:00
- 2018-10-04 0**7**:00

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using `arg_min()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/arg-min-aggfunction

```
let ProductsTable = datatable(Supplier: string, Fruit: string, Price: int, Purchase: datetime)
[
    'Contoso', 'Grapes', 220, datetime(2018-10-01 01:00),
    'Fabrikam', 'Lemons', 31, datetime(2018-10-01 02:00),
    'Contoso', 'Lemons', 29, datetime(2018-10-02 03:00),
    'Contoso', 'Grapes', 210, datetime(2018-10-02 04:00),
    'Fabrikam', 'Lemons', 30, datetime(2018-10-03 05:00),
    'Contoso', 'Bananas', 12, datetime(2018-10-03 06:00),
    'Contoso', 'Bananas', 12, datetime(2018-10-04 07:00),
    'Contoso', 'Lemons', 29, datetime(2018-10-04 08:00),
    'Contoso', 'Grapes', 200, datetime(2018-10-05 09:00),
];
ProductsTable
| summarize Price = arg_min(Price, *) by Supplier, Fruit
| order by Supplier asc, Fruit asc, Price asc
```

Comment: Hmm, for groups that have only one row, any() returns something else, incorrect. For example Contos/Grapes/200 returns 2018-10-01 01:00 while it should return 2018-10-05 09:00

Comment: right. I've misread the original description. answer is updated

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to Kusto but I found below could return the same output by using **partition by** and **row_number()** in Kusto.

**KQL:**

```
let ProductsTable = datatable(Supplier: string, Fruit: string, Price: int, Purchase: datetime) 
[
    'Contoso', 'Grapes', 220, datetime(2018-10-01 01:00),
    'Fabrikam', 'Lemons', 31, datetime(2018-10-01 02:00),
    'Contoso', 'Lemons', 29, datetime(2018-10-02 03:00),
    'Contoso', 'Grapes', 210, datetime(2018-10-02 04:00),
    'Fabrikam', 'Lemons', 30, datetime(2018-10-03 05:00),
    'Contoso', 'Bananas', 12, datetime(2018-10-03 06:00),
    'Contoso', 'Bananas', 12, datetime(2018-10-04 07:00),
    'Contoso', 'Lemons', 29, datetime(2018-10-04 08:00),
    'Contoso', 'Grapes', 200, datetime(2018-10-05 09:00), 
]; 
ProductsTable 
| partition by Fruit 
  ( sort by Price asc   
    | extend rn = row_number(1, prev(Supplier) != Supplier)   
    | where rn == 1
  ) 
| project Supplier, Fruit, Price, Purchase 
| sort by Supplier asc, Fruit asc;
```

Results:

```
Supplier    Fruit   Price   Purchase
Contoso     Bananas 12      2018-10-03 06:00:00.0000000
Contoso     Grapes  200     2018-10-05 09:00:00.0000000
Contoso     Lemons  29      2018-10-02 03:00:00.0000000
Fabrikam    Lemons  30      2018-10-03 05:00:00.0000000
```

However, this is not as efficient as Yoni L's solution. I was used to writing similar queries using Redshift/PostgreSQL so I was wondering if this could be done by row_num() which is a very common window function.